# Auto setup "permalink" or request notice

Tags: permalinks

I am trying to find a function or how to do.

When you install (or active) a theme.
1. I want to check if the link type is "permalink" or not.
2. If not, I want to make a notice saying "this theme is strongly recommend permalink"
or just setup permalink as default link.

How can I do that? please give me a tip. I can't really find any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user has left it on the default, i.e. not chosen a permalink scheme, by testing if `get_option( 'permalink_structure' )` is empty.

I don't think it's polite to just change the user's option for them, especially since they'll need to update their .htaccess or equivalent before it'd actually work. Here's a quick example to put in your theme's admin functions to emit a warning in the header:

```
if ( '' == get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
    function wpse157069_permalink_warning() {
        echo '<div id="permalink_warning" class="error">';
        echo '<p>We strongly recommend adding a <a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'options-permalink.php' ) ) . '">permalink structure</a> to your site when using WPSE AwesomeTheme.</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wpse157069_permalink_warning' );
}
```

---

A more-fully-formed solution (also [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/RupW/e85750191cd3c240855b)) with localisation and which only displays when appropriate:

```
if ( is_admin() && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    /* Admin-site only code */

    /**
     * If we don't have a permalink structure configured, and if the user has
     * permission to configure one, display a warning at the top of the admin
     * site. (We can't yet test which screen we're on.)
     */
    if ( ( '' == get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) &&
         current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        /**
         * If we're not already on the permalink configuration page, display a
         * warning recommending the administrator configure one.
         */
        function wpse_157069_permalink_warning() {
            $screen = get_current_screen();
            if ( ! isset( $screen ) || ( 'options-permalink' != $screen->id ) ) {
                echo '<div id="permalink_warning" class="error">';
                echo '<p>' . sprintf(
                     __( 'We strongly recommend adding a %s to your site when using WPSE AwesomeTheme.' ),
                     sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( admin_url( 'options-permalink.php' ) ),
                         __( 'permalink structure' ) ) ) . '</p>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wpse_157069_permalink_warning' );
    }
}
```